# Bootstrap column ordering not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have the following grid where I'm trying to display the image on the right and the text on the left for sm, md, and lg screens. However on xs screens I would like to reorder the image so that its above the text. When I try the push pull for
xs devices the entire layout gets messed up. Whats the correct way to achieve this?

```
<div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-xs-push-12">
                        <h3 class="h3 ">Some heading</h3>
                        <p>some text</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7 col-xs-pull-12" >
                        <img src="img/someimage.png" class="img-responsive" >
                    </div>
                </div>

 </div>
```

Comment: can you show us in a fiddle whats happening please

Comment: Its ok I've managed to fix it by working mobile first i.e. ordering the html how I want it to appear on an xs device and then using push pull to reorder on desktop devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed a s follows:

```
<div class="container">
          <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-7 col-sm-push-5" >
                    <img src="img/someimage.png" class="img-responsive" >
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-pull-7">
                    <h3 class="h3 ">Some heading</h3>
                    <p>some text</p>
                </div>

            </div>

 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

an easy way to fix this would be to hide some of the stuff at certain screen sizes:

```
<div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 visible-xs" >
                <img src="images/img_back.jpg" class="img-responsive" >
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5">
                <h3 class="h3 ">Some heading</h3>
                <p>some text</p>
            </div>

            <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-7" >
                <img src="images/img_back.jpg" class="img-responsive" >
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Basically the image is hidden at the top on every resolution except for xs. At all other sizes the bigger image is displayed to the right. This seems like it will be easier to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

You could create two rows, one for: large, medium and small screen.
And one for extra small screen.
[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/b9OyAKxFZBheKbVmhv2p?p=preview) a working example.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row hidden-xs">
    <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 ">
      <h3 class="h3">Some heading</h3>
      <p>some text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 ">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row visible-xs">
    <div class="col-xs-12 ">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 ">
      <h3 class="h3">Some heading</h3>
      <p>some text</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```