# bootstrap column order not working on xs screen

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, layout, grid

I'm making a row with 2 equal width columns. First one contains text and the second one an image. On lg/md/sm screen text will go left and the image in right as below code:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
       <div class="text-block">
           <h1>WordPress Theme Development</h1>
           <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</h3>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
       <div class="img-block text-center">
           <img src="assets/pics/wordpress.png" alt="WordPress">
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But on xs screen, I want the image top and text at the bottom. That's why I tried this below code which I followed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33488780/bootstrap-column-ordering-not-working) but it's not working

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-push-12">
                    <div class="text-block">
                        <h1>WordPress Theme Development</h1>
                        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-pull-12">
                    <div class="img-block text-center">
                        <img src="assets/pics/wordpress.png" alt="WordPress">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-md-push-6">
    <div class="img-block text-center">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/500x200/000/fff" alt="WordPress">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-md-pull-6">
    <div class="text-block">
      <h1>WordPress Theme Development</h1>
      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thnx for your reply, but I didn't get my answer. I want the image at the top and the text at the bottom of xs screen. And on lg/md/sm screen the text at left and the image ar right :)

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding.Updated answer

Comment: Thanx. Now I understand the code, the image should be the first column with the push as it will go at the top and the text should be the second column with the pull as it will go at the bottom. Am I right :)?